# Does Spirit still affect in-combat mana regeneration in Warlords of Draenor?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The [WoW wiki page on mana regeneration](http://www.wowwiki.com/Mana_regeneration) states Spirit does not affect in-combat mana regen:

> Spirit regenerates high amounts of mana, but **only out of combat.**
>   ...
>   `InCombatManaRegen = 5% of Base Mana` *[per what?]*
>   ...
>   Spirit will be the primary modifier of mana regen while out-of-combat and **only based on its affect to base-mana in-combat.**

However, this directly conflicts with the in-game tooltip:

[image: Spirit]

It's possible the tooltip was just never updated, but it's also possible the wiki was edited without real justification *(There are no working sources for that page)*.

**Has anyone done any Science™** or have a reliable source which explains how mana-regen works now?

Comment: Speaking purely from experience, Spirit does still *appear* to improve in-combat mana regeneration, suggesting that WoWWiki is out of date. I'll science it when I get home.

Comment: The "patch changes" section of that wiki also doesn't list any changes since 4.0.1. 
Since we know for a fact changes were made to regen in WoD, we can safely assume the page is out of date.

Comment: WoWWiki was nearly abandoned during the transition to Cataclysm. Wowpedia (http://wow.gamepedia.com/) was forked from it and is much more up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

4906 is your mana regenerated every 5 seconds. It consists of two parts.

First part is baseline healer mana regen with no spirit.
That's 0.4%/sec at level 100 [(source)](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/13087818929?page=6#118). For 5 seconds * 0.004 * 160000 mana = 3200 mana every 5 seconds.

For every point of spirit you get 0.412207024 mana per second [(source)](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/13087818929?page=7#128).
0.412207024 * 829 * 5 seconds = 1708.598 mana every 5 seconds.

3200 + 1708 = 4908.